# Showing comparison graph of different thread groups

Tags: jmeter

Is it possible in JMeter to show a graph of two scenarios in a single test plan? For e.g. - I want to show that how the system behaves with 10 thread group v/s 3000 thread group in a single plan.

Comment: Are these 2 different thread groups in your current test(!)?

Comment: @VinothS Yes I have 2 different scenarios.  I am testing a web service and I have to show to the management how the app is behaving with 10 v/s 500 users.  Can I do that using two thread groups in same test plan?

Comment: You run both of the threadgroup in the same time?

Comment: may or may not. it is pretty flexible and all I want is the graph from JMeter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

arm,

You need to understand that the test plan is wrong!!

You should not have 2 thread groups for the same scenario just for different thread numbers. Thread numbers can be parameterized using variables/properties. Even if you have 2 thread groups - you can not run them at the same time with different thread numbers and compare the results!!

---

- Just maintain 1 thread group for a business flow/scenario.
- Use Variables for thread number / ramp up etc
- Just run for 10 users first. Save the results.
- Then run the same test after some time with 500 users to compare the results with previous run.

---

Regarding the chart, `jp@gc - Response Times vs Threads`, `jp@gc - Transaction Throughput vs Threads` might be a good choice as you want to compare based on the number of users.

They do not come with JMeter by default. These are all external plugins. It is easy to install.

You can download those plugins [here](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionThroughputVsThreads/?utm_source=jmeter&utm_medium=helplink&utm_campaign=TransactionThroughputVsThreads).

Comment: Thanks, I thought I might be able to 2 thread groups in one plan.  Thank you for pointing that out.  I will look into those 2 things

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 ways for build graph:
1. Offline - after ending load test using result data in CSV file (Simple Data Writer node as well). And load data to Excel. Easy way, but suitable disposable.
2. Online (and Offline also) - using GraphiteSender on Listener. You can use this [instructions](http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-real-time-results-influxdb-grafana/). Hard, but beautiful and power tool.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think jMeter offers the opportunity to build graphs based on different tests/scenarios. Also I find jMeter own graph tool pretty unclear and not well developed to show information well.

I suggest to export your data to CSV and build your graphs with Excel or some equivalent software, in a couple of minutes you'll end with better data visualization.